# Synplify prunes my register when I use to_integer to access a Constant Array. (VHDL)

Tags: vhdl, fpga, synthesis

```
    Data_Out_SDa : process (SCl, IntReset) is
        variable IntSDa : std_logic;        -- Internal Sda
        begin  -- process Data_Out_SDa
        if IntReset = '0' then              -- asynchronous reset (active high)
           IntSDa := 'Z';
        elsif SCl'event and SCl = '0' then  -- falling clock edge
              IntSDa := DataBuffer(to_integer(unsigned(AddrReg)));
        end if;
        SDa <= IntSDa;
    end process Data_Out_SDa;
```

DataBuffer is a 121 bit constant std_logic_vector. Sda is an output port

The code synthesizes fine. But I get a warning Pruning Register IntSda, (CL169) and a warning Optimizing register bit IntSda to a constant 0 (Cl190)

For some reason the synthesize tool is interpreting that IntSda will always be 0. Note IntReset is an input. AddrReg is the output from a counter which changes value on the rising clock edge of SCl. The counter synthesizes fine and I have tested it on an FPGA and seen the output using a logic Analyzer. I'm at a loss for why this is happening. I could put a keep preserve, but I think that is a stop gap measure and no replacement for understanding the root cause.

Comment: Not enough information. If DataBuffer always equals zero, then IntSDa will too. The cause of this may be in a completely different part of your code.

Comment: DataBuffer is a constant 121 bit std_logic_vector made up of 'Z' and '0'. I didn't put it there because of the code formatting. 
          constant DataBuffer : std_logic_vector(0 to n-1) := ...
Also Sda is an output port.

Comment: I think 'Z' value only allowable with three-state logic (a combinational). As I know, you are trying to put it on register :-?. I think it's impossible.

Comment: Well as Dang and Philippe mentioned, any registered constant will be removed and Z is only supported on the IOs or internal IOs that support high impedance, but I don't know any FPGA that support constant Z value. And why on earth do you want to waste a register on a constant anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll struggle to get Zs out that way. The synthesizer is probably treating them as '0's :)

I suggest you use 1s and 0s in the `DataBuffer` array and then drive `SDa` outside the process like this:

```
SDa <= '0' when IntSDa = '0' else 'Z';
```

Comment: Thanks! That was it. It makes sense how would the FPGA know how to store an high impedance state!

Comment: @Mayank: welcome to Stack Overflow - if you found the answer helpful please upvote, and if it's the complete answer, use the "tick" icon to mark it as "answered".

Comment: I apparently don't have enough of a reputation to up vote you. But thanks for the info.